# C#.Net Core 3.1 HttpRequest timeout or SSL connection issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, request

Ok i have the following code

```
HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
clientHandler.UseProxy = false;

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
{
    var reqUri = string.Format("{0}/{1}?getBIC=true&validateBankCode=true", AppSettings.Instance.ValidationSettings.IBANValidationUri, iban);
    Logger.Instance.LogInfo("IBAN Validation: Sending request");
    using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(reqUri))
    {
        using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
        {
            if (content != null)
            {
                Logger.Instance.LogInfo("IBAN Validation: Reading data");
                var data = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Result))
                {
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IBANValidationResult>(data.Result);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now this code simply makes a rquest to the **openiban api** to get the specific bank information from a IBAN number.

This code runs on a ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API that is running on a IIS Server.

Now we have 3 exact same server with the same web api.

The problem:

- when i call the service from a browser on server 1, the service works fine i get the response etc.
- when i call the service from a browser on server 2 it works also fine.
- when i call the service from a browser on server 3 it takes too long and then i receive following error on the backend:

> ERROR: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner
> exception
>
> ERROR: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the
> transport stream.

The funny thing is: This issue does not depend on one server, sometimes the server 3 works but then server 2 does not work, sometimes server 1 does not work an the other servers are working.

Does anybody have a clue what is going on here?

PS: The SSL certificates are installed on the server

Thanks a lot

Comment: Use a tool like Wireshark to analyze the actual SSL/TLS handshake packets. That should reveal the differences and the cause.

Comment: You also could use IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool to generate a dump file to analyze the cause of the problem. how to use [IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-a-process-that-has-stopped-responding-in-iis-995db9a3-a3be-6d20-cf2f-c48101a64444)